# Could not retrieve json data from the given format

Tags: json, jsonp

this is my json format

```
({"message":{"success":true,"result":[{"lead_no":"LEA13","lastname":"Developer","firstname":"PHP","company":"Dummies","email":"nandhajj@gmail.com","id":"10x132"},{"lead_no":"LEA14","lastname":"Venu","firstname":"Yatagiri","company":"Rsalesarm","email":"veve@jajs.com","id":"10x133"},{"lead_no":"LEA4","lastname":"Jones","firstname":"Barbara","company":"Vtigercrm inc","email":"barbara_jones@company.com","id":"10x35"},{"lead_no":"LEA1","lastname":"Smith","firstname":"Mary","company":"Vtiger","email":"mary_smith@company.com","id":"10x32"}]}})
```

i am trying to retrieve the whole json result values using the following snippet

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        alert(xmlHttp.status);
        if(xmlHttp.status==200)
        {

        alert("hi");
        var jsondata=eval("("+xmlHttp.responseText+")") //retrieve result as an JavaScript object
        jsonOutput=jsondata.result;
        alert(jsonOutput);

        InitializeLeadStorage()

        }
    }
```

my `alert (hi )` is displayed but the `alert(jsonOutput);` is undefined , please help me if you could  find any mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jsonOutput = jsondata.message.result;
```

`result` lives on `message` - it is not a top-level item in the JSON. With things like this, `console.log()` the JSON and you can check the path to the bit you want.

Also

- your variable is global
- there are better ways of parsing your JSON. If you don't care about old IEs, you can use the ECMA5 `JSON.parse()`, else use jQuery or another third-party utility for this

Comment: jsonOutput = jsondata.message.result;
i used this , but still its haunting me , i dont find any change

Comment: How do you mean change? Does `jsondata.message.result` hold the value you expect it to or not?

Comment: actually it holds a array ,i checked it by   alert(jsonOutput); using this alert , it displays undefined

Comment: Yes, it holds an array of objects. That's what the JSON data you posted shows should happen.

Comment: but y isnt displayed in the alert (jsonOutput)

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: Go to JSFiddle.net and recreate your environment - JS, HTML etc.

Comment: k i have got some improvement in my result now the alert displays [object object] 4 times  do u have any idea why its not displaying the value

Comment: Because you are alerting an array which contains objects. If you want to retrieve a particular value from *within* one of those objects, you'll have to delve deeper, i.e. beyond `jsondata.message.result`. Example, to get the `lead_no` property of the first object, the path would be `jsondata.message.result[0].lead_no`. This is all about object traversal.

Comment: yeah it worked  , but is there any way by which i can get the whole array

Comment: i consider your comment as a solution to my problem but how to mark it as answer